# Can MvcMiniProfiler display SQL parameter values?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mvc-mini-profiler

I've been trying out [MvcMiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) as replacement for [EFTracingProvider](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/) since it's so much simpler to configure.

It will display the sql just fine, but I'd like to see the parameter values as well.

```
insert [dbo].[PersonName]([Prefix], [GivenName], [MiddleName], [FamilyName], [Affix])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
select [Id]
from [dbo].[PersonName]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = scope_identity()
```

**Can MvcMiniProfiler display sql parameter values?**

Here's my Global.asax. I'm using EF 4.3.1 with code-first.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialize();

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start(ProfileLevel.Verbose);
    }
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want the SQL Server Formatter, try adding:

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = 
    new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.SqlServerFormatter();
```

In `Application_Start`

Comment: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/MiniProfiler/MiniProfiler/StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters A couple of notes: 1) It adds the parameters above the sql in a declare statement, which is convenient for copy pasting and running directly in ssms.  2) It seems like you can add the line above in _BeginRequest as well, it doesn't have to be in Application_Start.  In my case I wanted to control the formatting with a runtime parameter.  NULL it out if you want NO SQL to show or see the documentation for other formatters.