# Can the ServiceStack MiniProfiler show SQL parameter values, not just the bound parameter names?

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler, ormlite-servicestack

I've got the ServiceStack [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling) enabled in my AppHost (in Application_Start), and I can view the SQL generated by OrmLite in my page. (using SS v3.9.59.0)

What I **can't** see in the profile trace is the values of bound parameters. So if OrmLite translates a LINQ expression into @0, I can't see the value sent to the DB as part of the query.

Here's an example trace from the profiler:

```
SELECT "SettingGroup" , "SettingKey" , "LastModified" , "SettingValue"  
FROM "GlobalSetting"
WHERE (("SettingGroup" = @0) AND ("SettingKey" = 'a3849d59864b252a2022b4b8a164add1'))
```

I'd really like to know what value was sent for `@0` for this query.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Profiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new InlineFormatter(true);
    new AppHost().Init();
}
```

I've tried a few variants of the `Profiler.Settings.SqlFormatter` property:

- `SqlFormatter = new InlineFormatter();`
- `SqlFormatter = new InlineFormatter(true);`
- `SqlFormatter = new SqlServerFormatter();`
- Not setting `SqlFormatter` at all, leaving it at its default value

All of them have the same result, only showing `@0` but not its value.

If I click the "Share" link, I can see the both the bound parameter name and its value in the resulting JSON array. I just can't see it in the rendered profiler output.

Any ideas what I need to do to show the parameter values?

Answer (score 4):

Answer can be found here : [Can MvcMiniProfiler display SQL parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994903/can-mvcminiprofiler-display-sql-parameter-values)

Add this to Application_Start

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = 
    new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.SqlServerFormatter();
```

However there seems to be a small issue when using nvarchar / varchar as parameter type. See this [topic](http://community.miniprofiler.com/permalinks/164/entity-framework-sql-output-incorrect).

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. The code snippet you posted works for the original MvcMiniProfiler project, not from the fork embedded within ServiceStack. The SS-forked code would be:
    Profiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.SqlFormatters.SqlServerFormatter();
but that still doesn't work. I only see the @0 symbol but not the value of @0